# How to use Asynctask establish socket connections?

Tags: java, android, sockets, android-asynctask

Recent study utilizing Asynctask to establish socket connections, but encountered some situation
now I can use to press the button to establish a connection, , but I do not know how to make the button text from "unconnected" to "Connected ".Compile no problem but it can not be executed on the simulator, press the button, I can see a text from "unconnected" to "Connected", but the next second forced off the APP.

**The following is my code fragment:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public static Button Btn_Wifi,Btn_Power,Btn_Flame;
    public static Boolean connected=false;  
    public static DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = null;
    public static DataInputStream dataInputStream = null ;
    public static Socket socket;
```

**AsyncTask:**

```
static class SocketTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void > {
    @Override
    protected Void  doInBackground(Void ... parms) {                
            try {
                socket = new Socket("ip", port);//
                dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());//and stream                              
                changeConnectionStatus(true);//change the connection status                 
            }catch (UnknownHostException e) {                   
            }catch (IOException e) {
            }finally {
                try {
                    socket.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }                   
            }               
        return null;
    }   
};
```

**Button.OnClickListener:**

```
Button.OnClickListener BtnWifiOnClickListener = new Button.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        //SocketTask sockettask = new SocketTask();
        new SocketTask().execute();
    }
};
```

**changeConnectionStatus:**

```
public static void changeConnectionStatus(Boolean isConnected) {
    connected=isConnected;//change variable 
    if(isConnected){//if connection established
        Btn_Wifi.setText("connected");
        Btn_Power.setEnabled(true);     

    }else{
        Btn_Wifi.setText("unconnected");
        Btn_Power.setText("POWER OFF");
        Btn_Power.setEnabled(false);
        PowerStatus(false); 
    }   
}
```

**Positive solutions**

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        changeConnectionStatus(true);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't touch UI from `doInBackground()`

you need to use `onPostExecute()`

move the call of `changeConnectionStatus(true)` from `doInBackground`() as following:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute() {
    changeConnectionStatus(true);
}
```

Comment: Wonderful, I do it!
The original concept is so simple ...
I think I'm really not familiar to Asynctask